# A mysterious situation with jQuery or am I blind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a jQuery code and the html code on my page. The code loads two php files on two DIVs, based on the value of a drop down list. The code is working great, loading pic and everything. However I have a small problem.

When I place the second div ( artistdetails ) inside of a seperated div from the first div, the loading pic does not appears on the second but only in the first. Content is appeared correctly though.
As I saw in firebug, the class is loading fine. I even changed the picture to something bigger but nothing was there. ( I mean the pic is not hidden somewhere).

I made a lot of experiment, I set the ID to the float:left div but nothing happens. I really need to have them in a separated DIV. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start looking at the final generated code (which you might post here or on pastebin.com with a link).

Sounds to me like something in the php forms is probably not generating valid html.  For example, an unclosed entity.

Answer (score 0):

It must work, i guess, if the class is added to `<div  id="artistdetails"></div>`

Still try something like this

```
$('#artistdetails').empty()
    .addClass('loading')
    .load('forms/' + val + 'b.php', 
        function(){
            setTimeout(
                function(){ $('#artistdetails').removeClass('loading') },
                 2000);
    });
```